# Bash script with multiple arguments

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am new to Bash scripts so I was wondering if I could get some help figuring out this simple problem.
I currently have a python file that I run in the command line that I would like to automate in bash with following arguments python xxx.py **file1.csv** **99 99 700 900 0.005 9** --use_cuda **Y** **10** &> **nameooutputfile.txt** &     (anything in bold is passed to the bash script as a argument and non-bold commands are static)

Here is what I tried so far:

```
if python xxx.py $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 --use_cuda $8 $9 &> ${10} &; then
    echo "xxx.py completed succesfully!"
else
    echo "Error: xxx.py failed!"
fi
```

But I am getting the following error when I ran the script:

```
line 45: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
ine 45: `if python xxx.py $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 --use_cuda $8 $9 &> ${10} &; then'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `&;` by `;`.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you for the fast response! the reason I have the "&" at the end is because I would like the command to still run in the background even after logging off.

Comment: nvm @choroba answered that question. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to keep the script running after logging off, call the whole shell script with `nohup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `&` and `;` are valid command separators, they can't be combined into one, though.

`&` is used to run the command in the background, checking its return value in an `if` would just check whether the job was able to fork, so you probably want to use just `;`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!